# Phone Number Validations

Tags: forms, validation, input, phone-number, clean-architecture

Suppose you're making a Sign-Up Form which takes your phone number as a detail with respect to all the other details . So let's say , I added some validations, say for example :

`1. Phone number length should not be greater than 10`

`2. User should not be allowed to write any special characters too`

After giving the basic validation checks, I went on to check if everything's working fine or not and suddenly I type `1111111111` in my box.

Now, lets say you're developing it for India, now you know this is not a valid phone number or a user adding `1110001231` does not make any sense.

**So, is it good to give validation checks to check if the number provided is correct or not (assuming you don't have an OTP page to validate that number) or is it over-engineering stuffs ?**

And if you make it for one country, say India, how would one approach to scale it for different countries ?

I went on to some webapps such as Zomato, Swiggy which had only basic or no validations as such , but then Flipkart or Amazon return an error .

Since, I am a fresher I would like to know what people think of it in the industry. Does basic validation satisfy or validating if its a correct number ( no OTP , etc) from the frontend a better user experience

I tried only having basic validations . When I tried simulating it to a friend (assuming he is the client), he asked me why was I letting the user type `1111111111` and let him sign up.

We had a discussion but was time bounded and hence would just like to know the perspective of different developers as in what do they tend to follow ?

Comment: Best user experience: don't ask for a phone number. Unless you really need it for something. Then the level of validation needed depends on your expected usage. Note: collecting phone numbers from certain countries may involve data protection legislation and similar nightmares

Comment: @teapot418 I agree with you on the data protection and other nightmares but lets just go with the assumption of a basic webpage and all I need to know about validations . Do you think not letting the user type 1111111111 as their number is better ? 
( Thinking in terms of a basic rookie level )

Comment: [Some fun facts about phone numbers.](https://github.com/google/libphonenumber/blob/master/FALSEHOODS.md) International phone numbers are an unholy inconsistent mess. I wouldn't try to validate them. Second choice: [use a library](https://github.com/google/libphonenumber)

Comment: Thanks @teapot418. Highly appreciate you taking out the time , reading through the question and feeding me with great resources. Definitely helping me in my argument and knowledge . Kudos